# Call function via url in PHP

Tags: php, function, url, include

**Index.php**

```
<?php include("http://localhost/test/link.php"); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo "ECHOXXX: " . xyz();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**link.php**

```
<?php
    echo "hiii";
    function xyz()
    {
        return "TRUE";
    }
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
hiii
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function xyz() in C:\wamp64\www\test\index.php
on line 13
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function xyz() in C:\wamp64\www\test\index.php on line 13
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  410392  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
```

How can I call that function via URL ? I must use URL here. Because sometime we may fetch data from different server.

Comment: You can't read someone's source code (except from HTML/CSS/JS), with an `include()` of an URL. That would be very bad and insecure.

Comment: But we ll use it in our server.. is there any way out there for this ?

Comment: Yes, include the relative path (or even absolute) of your PHP file on the server.

Comment: What if it is a complete different server. I need to pass the function through url only ..

Comment: Then you'll have to implement some sort of API, REST or SOAP maybe?

Comment: REST is what I am trying now. Thanks for the response